# iTunes Connect application is missing required architecture

Tags: app-store-connect, loader

iTunes Connect is saying that my application executable is missing required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6

Now thats funny (read: peculiar) to me because I specifically set iOS target to be 4.0, and compiled with armv7

MinimumOSVersion is even set to 4.2 in the info.plist

Why would I get this error? This is an update to an app that was never put up for sale, it is approved to be on the app store but just placeholding because there were bugs I wanted to fix. Does the application loader check that deeply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you have to uncheck: "Build Active Architecture only" , in Xcode 3 this requires you to select your target, and click "Info", in the build tab it is a check box under architecture –

Comment: This is the right one, do not bother yourself with the other posts recommending installing older XCode

Answer (score 0):

Not to beat a dead horse (thread), but I found a different solution to this problem when it occurs for builds of apps that must run on iOS 6 (currently on Xcode 4.6.2).

[The solution was here.](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/One-Major-problem-in-Application-72283.S.174223497)

And the steps are:

> 1. select your Build architecture as Standard (armv7 &armv7s)
> 2. select deployment target as IOS 4.3 and
> 3. add the following variable in the `info.plist`:- Required Device capabilities with Item0 values as armv7.

I already had "Build active architecture only" set to "No," so there is at least one more new-ish issue that causes this same error.