# application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture must be present armv7

Tags: xcode, app-store, distribution, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393701/iphone-ipod-touch-application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture)

I have tried three days for solving this problem.
I want to update my iOs application but i can not submit appStore for this reason.
I am using Xcode 4.2 iOs 5 sdk.

Comment: I tried all of that solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Is armv6 listed in you Target, Build Settings, Architectures, for your Distribution/Archive build?

If not, make it so.

Comment: I did it but in my xcode architecture under lines releases how can i make distribution.