# errors when trying to use application loader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, app-store

I am finally done with my first app but have the worst time trying to upload the binary to the app store.
I am failing at the stage were I send my Binarries with application loader.
Here is what I have done:
I went to the products folder in Xcode and zipped the myAppName.app file.I have used that file with application loader but get something like 6 errors.
[image]

I feel that it is really complicated to submit your app but I'm sure that some of you out there are quite smart and can help me figure this nightmare out.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you have all your icon files in your project and also create entries in the plist.  Here is the link for instructions.  Scroll down a bit to see the plist information
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

If you don't mind me asking.  Why are you using application loader versus just using xcode to submit to the store?

Comment: Thanks, all my icons are in the project file, I went and looked in the plist and there were some other icon names listed there for some reason. after deleting them the errors regarding the icons are gone.unfortunately I'm still left with 2 errors, the top and button one, but getting closer

Comment: Check out this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393701/iphone-ipod-touch-application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture  Also for the other error check out this thread.  It might be something with your signing profiles http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1019796

Comment: thanks again, I tried to edit the built architecture per the other post but I'm coming up with the same two errors.BTW the icon names in the plist are different from the standart names but I do have 4 icons, do I need to give them their conventional name i.e icon-72 etc?

Comment: I don't think the icon names make a difference but I am not 100% sure.  I guess it would give you an error if icon were missing. Did you check the distribution profile that it set correctly to fix the last error?

Comment: i still have the first and last error, I changed the compiler think per the subject of your referral, not sure hoe to check the distribution profile vs the app profile to see what the problem is.

Comment: What is your iOS target set to?  check out these two links for other suggestions to fix the first error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393701/iphone-ipod-touch-application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture   http://www.linkedin.com/groups/One-Major-problem-in-Application-72283.S.174223497

Comment: yeah thanks Yan, i got rid of the first message by changing the target  deployment to 6.0, but the last one is still remaining no matter what i try.

Comment: Can you try to archive and submit using xcode and organizer?  It might give you a more informative error.  Most likely it has something to do with distribution profile not setup right either in xcode or in itunes connect.